# Xcode 13 dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/LinkPresentation.framework/LinkPresentation

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I am getting this error when building on my iPAd Air emulator. I have the framework included in my build phase. Any ideas?

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/LinkPresentation.framework/LinkPresentation
  Referenced from: /Users/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A87BB772-9E8A-47A5-8D11-F300B549BDB4/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/AEF2517C-5E9D-4295-8F31-3D91D4668C57/myracnative.app/myracnative
  Reason: image not found
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries
DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myracnative-glxuojrfejxbhqgircpjgklctbto/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 12.0.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib
DYLD_ROOT_PATH=/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 12.0.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot
DYLD_FALLBACK_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 12.0.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks
DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 12.0.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 12.0.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 12.0.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/Developer/Library/P
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using a beta ver of Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

Set `LinkPresentation.framework` to `Optional` on your SS (similarly to the `SwiftUI.framework`)

Comment: This worked for me. I was having a problem where my app would crash on iOS 12 and earlier but worked fine on iOS 13 and up.